# How to know all the websites hosted on that webserver?

Tags: web, webserver

For eg. I want to know all the google websites So, on [this website](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/) I searched for google.com and I get 61 domains.

But in that I missed one website which is https://research.google.com So, when I type this website, I got 62 domains.

Why is it so and how to get all the websites under single webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to list the different domains or the subdomains as well?

If you want to display the subdomains as well, you can take a look here:
https://security.stackexchange.com/q/35078/18541